# How to get the picture's shooting time in android development?

Tags: android, file, bitmap, android-contentprovider

```
String picPath = "/mnt/sdcard/yepcolor/sina.png";
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picPath);
```

I know the 'picPath' of the picture.Now, I want to get the picture's shooting time,and what should I do?Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, png files doesn't contain such information. If you are reading jpeg files, however, you can use [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html).

Comment: Some jpeg files do not contain any message. But it works in some  cases .Nice,done it.